IntelliJ IDEA compiler ignores changes on build if project is stored on WSL
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.6 and WSL on Windows 11. Everything works properly, except for some weird issues when the compiler ignores the most recent class changes. The project directory \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\<path-to-directory> is added as the exclusion for Windows Defender.
The only solution I came up with is to perform a Rebuild Project (Ctrl + F9 Build does not work) before every execution of Java application or to execute mvn clean/delete target folder manually. It is very annoying to do it and takes some time whenever I want to rerun the project with some minor changes.
Did anyone experience a similar issue?

There is related issue under investigation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-341365/Compiler-is-ignoring-changes-when-the-project-is-open-from-wsl.localhost

My solution so far (not perfect) was to add a task to run before launch and that task is running, in my case, the compile and test-compile from maven to ensure compilation of changes in classes.

I have tried something similar. I added a task "mvn clean" task that runs before run/debug configuration and it worked. But it is still a workaround and not a real solution.
